# reverse ssh run in rc.local : Host key verification failed

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I am trying to run reverse ssh in background by using this command

`ssh -N -R 2222:localhost:22 -p 22 user@ip`

The question is I can run this command manually and everything is fine but when I put this command to rc.local and reboot, it showed Host key verification failed.
I found some solution like delete the known_hosts but it still not working.

Also, I added a public key in order to login without password

Anyone can answer my question? Please.